DatePicker width exceeds Window size
I have a KivyMD DatePicker widget which pops up on button press within my kivyMD App. However, when I set the Window.size=(360,640)in my main.py file the window size works but the DatePicker doesn't fit accordingly. Manually resizing the window by dragging the corner immediately adjusts the DatePicker size accordingly. How can I make it such that the DatePicker fits the window size without manual intervention?
main.py
#KivyMD 0.104.2
#python 3.8.6

from datetime import datetime
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker

Window.size=(360,640)

class DashScreen2(MDScreen):

    def show_date_picker(self):
        present_date=datetime.today()
        present_year=present_date.year
        present_month=present_date.month
        present_day=present_date.day
        date_dialog=MDDatePicker(min_year=present_year,max_year=present_year+3)
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save,on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        date_dialog.open()

    def on_save(self,instance,value,date_range):
        self.manager.get_screen("DashSum").ids.date_selected.text=str(value)

    def on_cancel(self,instance,value):
        pass



class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        WindowManager=ScreenManager()
        WindowManager.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name="Welcome"))
        WindowManager.add_widget(DashScreen2(name='Dash2'))
        return WindowManager

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()


myapp.kv
<DashScreen2>:
    name:'Dash2'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                size_hint_y:0.2
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.75,'center_y':0.4}
                spacing:10
                
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "Set date"
                    icon:'calendar'
                    on_press: root.show_date_picker()
           

The Result:
The DatePicker width exceeds the Window size
